# When do I get a mkdocs error on build command of Docker?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, mkdocs

I just started trying out Docker and I'm trying to resolve their first tutorial.
When I run the command docker `build -t docker101tutorial` I get an error saying `ERROR [build 2/2] RUN mkdocs build`.
Does anyone know how to solve it or has run to it before?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?